# How to give priority levels to grammars in SAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, speech, sapi

I'm creating a speech recognition application using SAPI. I need to be able to give different priority levels to the different grammars that I use. (dictation grammar and other grammar that I defined) I need the recognizer to search in the grammar that I defined and look in to the dictation grammar only if the speech input is not matching to any words in the grammar that I defined.
For now I have a code like this:

```
Grammar myGram;
Choices myEditor = new Choices();
myEditor.Add("public");
//adding other choices
myGram = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(myEditor));
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
recognizer.LoadGrammar(myGram);
Grammar dictation = new DictationGrammar();
dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar";
recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation);
recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(
               SpeechRecognizedHandler);
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Please give me any ideas on how to prioritize myGram over dictation grammar. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use SRGS compliant grammars you can use [weights](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/#S2.4.1) to basically assign priority levels. The [Grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar.aspx) object does support xml-formatted grammars that comply with the [W3C SRGS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/).